# Azure ARM template script error when creating certificate for apex domain

Tags: azure, certificate

Really scratching my head on this one, I keep getting the error below:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SubjectName'.
> At azure_cli_-_create_cert.ps1:12 char:80

for the Azure ARM template script below:

```
     $subscription = ""
       $resourceGroupName = ""
       $appServicePlanName = ""
       $subjectName = ""
                
       Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscription
                
       $appServicePlan = Get-AzureRmResource `
                 | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -eq $resourceGroupName} `
                 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $appServicePlanName}
         
       New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SubjectName $subjectName -AppServicePlanName $appServicePlanName -Location $appServicePlan.Location -TemplateFile "CreateHttpFreeCert.json"
```

Does anyone know why this is?

I am running the script in a windows powershell script (i.e. .ps1 script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to supply the parameters for your template in as a JSON file using `-TemplateParameterFile` or `-TemplateParameterObject`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment?view=azurermps-6.13.0#example-1--use-a-custom-template-and-parameter-file-to-create-a-deployment

Comment: The script is one provided by Microsoft directly for creating SSL certificates. I'm not sure what exactly is the "CreateHttpFreeCert.json". Are you saying that file needs to exist within the same directly as the .ps1 script?

Comment: Yes. You need `CreateHttpFreeCert.json` file in the same directory as your script. ARM template (which should be you json file) can be found here: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/02/asmc-apex-domain.html#arm-template

Comment: Thanks Willy, I changed simply "-Location $appServicePlan.Location" to "-Location $appServicePlan.Location[0]" and the script ran successfully.